# How to activate RequestScope inside CompletableFuture (getting org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException)

Tags: asynchronous, jakarta-ee, completable-future

I'm developing a JEE Web Application (no Spring), and I'm getting this exception.

```
class org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException,message=WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

From a JSF Backing bean I'm calling a method in an aplication scoped class, and this method executes asynchronously some

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> methodInTransactionGoingToRepository()}
```

However I'm getting that exception because it runs with no Request Context.
I know I could isolate these calls in Rest APi and make some Async Posts, and it would work.
But the application is small, and not suitable to have other services.

How can I solve this. Is there a way to activate a Request Scope before calling `methodInTransactionGoingToRepository();`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You _can't_ "solve this". You run `runAsync`, i.e. in a different thread, your context is lost. Run in the same thread if you want it to work.

Comment: So, I can't execute a method asynchronously in JEE7. No workaround?, i.e, other than using rest api or JMS?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the insight BalusC. Actually I've alreadu tried with EJB asynchronous methods.
`class Backingbean  {
@EJB
private MyService  }`

And MyService annotated with `@Local @Singleton (or @Stateless)`, with the asynchronous method I want to call from the Backing bean, and the same exception is thrown:

**No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped**

Comment: I'm searching for it. But what I exactly want  is to run assynchronously a method inside a CDI Bean( a method to process a validation that needs to go to read and write into a repository).  The method is now acceptin one argument (a Long id)